# SQL window functions: Performance impact of returning the same avg() many times?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to SELECT a bunch of rows from table A, along with the results of aggregate functions like avg(A.price) and avg(A.distance).

Now, the SELECT query takes a good bit of time, so I don't want to run one query to get the rows, and other to get the averages. If I did that, I'd be running the query to SELECT the appropriate rows twice.

But looking at the PostgreSQL window function documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html), it seems that using window function to return the results of the aggregate functions I want to use alongside the returned rows means that every single row returned would contain the results of the aggregate functions. And in my case, since the aggregation is over all the rows returned by the main SELECT query and not a subset of its rows, this seems wasteful.

What are the performance implications of returning the same avg() many times, given that I'm selecting a subset of the rows in A but doing aggregate queries across the entire subset? In particular, does Postgres recompute the average every time, or does it cache the average somehow?

By way of analogy: If you look at the window function docs and pretend that `depname` is 'develop' for every row returned by the SELECT query, and that the average is the same for every row because the average was computed across all returned rows. How many times is that average computed?

Comment: If you benchmark this you will certainly find that PostgreSQL is smart enough to not recompute the average for each row.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I don't know, but I would guess that Postgres only re-computes the value of the Window function each time the "frame" is different. If the frame is defined to include all rows in the result set, this will never happen, so the same value will simply be output again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CTE to do what you want.  According to the Postgres [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html):

> A useful property of WITH queries is that they are evaluated only once
>   per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred to more
>   than once by the parent query or sibling WITH queries. Thus, expensive
>   calculations that are needed in multiple places can be placed within a
>   WITH query to avoid redundant work. Another possible application is to
>   prevent unwanted multiple evaluations of functions with side-effects.
>   However, the other side of this coin is that the optimizer is less
>   able to push restrictions from the parent query down into a WITH query
>   than an ordinary sub-query. The WITH query will generally be evaluated
>   as stated, without suppression of rows that the parent query might
>   discard afterwards. (But, as mentioned above, evaluation might stop
>   early if the reference(s) to the query demand only a limited number of
>   rows.)

You can structure you final results using a structure such as:

```
with cte as (your basic select goes here)
select *
from cte cross join
     (select averages here
      from cte
     ) const
where < your row filter here>
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely worked. However, a window function whose output was equivalent ended up being faster for me for some reason. It's good to know about WITH but I wonder how I can determine why the window function was faster.

Comment: @zach . . . If I had to speculate on why the window function is faster, it is because this version saves out all the data (unfiltered), whereas the window function version does not.

Answer (score 5):

According to [section 7.2.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WINDOW) of the doc:

> When multiple window functions are used, all the window functions having syntactically equivalent PARTITION BY and ORDER BY clauses in their window definitions are guaranteed to be evaluated in a single pass over the data.